# Open c# app in Excel without using VBA

Tags: c#, excel

I'm not sure if this can be done, but I'd like to have an Excel Workbook, with a button, and when that button is clicked, it opens a C# console app that does some work on the sheet. The catch is that it would be done without VBA code.

The reason for this is that due to Ransomware attacks in the last few months, we've locked down all Office VBA, and are trying to get away from using it in Excel where possible. I could create a C# application that opens a workbook and does the work, but users would be happier with a button in the workbook they can click, as it's what they know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at creating a [VSTO add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268878.aspx).

Comment: Interesting, because without VBA you probably face file locks as well

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I wanted to avoid a VSTO, as it's something else the user has to do manually (adding it in), rather than just click a button. I might have to settle for an external .exe that picks up the file automatically and does what's needed to it.